# html anchor works only once

Tags: html, anchor

I am ashamed to say that I have an anchor issue.

So I have this code:

```
<a name="map"></a>

$("div.store_list").click(function() {          
    //do some stuff         
    location.href = location.href + '#map'
});
```

When doing the first click it works fine. And the URL changes to:

```
http://mydomain.local/stores#map
```

Second click the URL changes to the following and it doesn't work:

```
http://mydomain.local/stores#map#map
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was solved using: `document.location = "#map";`

Answer (score 4):

In case you scroll and need to jump again, this has worked for me:

```
onclick="location.hash=''; location.hash='#map';"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) instead, e.g.

```
location.hash='#map'
```

Comment: this will only work once. If you scroll again and invoke the click function the anchoring will not work. Solved by simply using ... document.location = "#map";

Comment: I don't understand why this would be expected to solve the issue, and in fact it appears to produce the same result

Answer (score 1):

Reseting the scroll position on anchor link click event worked for me.
Seems like [theres at least one bug](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/11993079?hl=en) with anchor links in Chrome versions 76 - 86 (The most recent macOS version at time of this posting).

Try:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check to make sure the URL doesn't already contain the value you're appending:

```
$("div.store_list").click(function() {          
    //do some stuff
    if (location.href.indexOf('#map') == -1) {         
        location.href += '#map';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution didn't work for me sadly.  I managed to get it to work in Chrome by setting the anchor value to "#" first, then setting it to my desired location.

```
document.location.href = "#";
document.location.href = "#myAnchor";
```

Once I did this, it fired every time I click a link with an anchor tag in it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.jump_to_instance', e => {

    // Get anchor name
    var anchorName = $(e.target).attr("href");

    // Set anchor to nothing first
    document.location.href = "#";

    // Set to new anchor value
    document.location.href = anchorName;
});

<a href="#myAnchor">Click me to go to anchor, I should work multiple times</a>

<div id="myAnchor">Will jump to here</div>
```